# How can I solve Navigator.push() error in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

There are Error Messagge, Error Code and some HomePageCode.
What is matter??

I did that error message said to do.
But I CAN'T SOLVE PLOBLEM.

[Error Message]

```
lib/create_page.dart:194:63: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
     context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context) => HomePage()),
                                                             ^
 lib/home_page.dart:10:3: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
     HomePage(this.user);
              ^^^^^^^^
```

[Error Code]

```
Navigator.push(
  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context) => HomePage()),
);
```

[HomePage]

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
final FirebaseUser user;

HomePage(this.user);
```

Answer (score 1):

As for the `HomePage` class, you need to pass a `FirebaseUser`  instance. If you like to make it optional, you can use named argument constructor with nullable datatype.

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final FirebaseUser? user;

  const HomePage({super.key, this.user});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `HomePage` widget expects an argument of type `FirebaseUser`. You need to add this argument in the navigator

```
Navigator.push(
  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context) => HomePage(user)),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final FirebaseUser user;
```

here user is required argument,which is causing the error,
either you pass it or make it nullable like

```
final FirebaseUser? user;
```

Answer (score 0):

`HomePage` class has a contractor so you should enter the right arguments.

if you want your argument to be optional you should make `user` can be null by using the:

```
final FirebaseUser? user;
```

i use [**Getx**](https://pub.dev/packages/get/install)   to handle Navigator and state manager

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:ttest/screen/homepage.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
     
      home:Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: (){
          Get.to(HomePage());

        }),
      ));
  }
}
```

and for `HomePage` file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {

   final FirebaseUser? user;

  const HomePage({super.key, this.user});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
);
  }
}

class FirebaseUser {
}
```

Comment: Error: The getter 'user' isn't defined for the class '_CreatePageState'.
 - '_CreatePageState' is from 'package:insta_clone2_start/create_page.dart' ('lib/create_page.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'user'.
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context) => HomePage(user)),

Comment: I tested the code and it give me other errors so  i edited my answer and i give you the full code i hope this will work for you